# iOS - Create NSString that contains "

Tags: html, ios, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I want to create a NSString that contains some HTML-Code. But as the HTML code contains a " the string ends too early.

This is the HTML code I want to add.

```
<FONT FACE="arial">arial font</FONT>
```

This is how I do it:

```
NSString *myHTMLcode = @"<FONT FACE="arial">arial font</FONT>"
```

As you can see, it stops too early (before the arial)
What do I have to do in order to get a NSString that contains a "?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard (Objective-)C(++) *escape character*:

```
@"A string with a quote \", a tab \t, a new line \n, and a backslash \\";
```

Comment: +1 for (Objective-)C(++)

Comment: Why not just vote to close the duplicate? Don't we have enough duplicates around here already?